# Microsoft Azure emulator 2.6 error in installation

Tags: azure

my azure installation for visual studio 2012 professtional is generating error while downloading azure emulator 2.6.
The error says the product did not download successfully : the underlying connection was closed : An unexpected error occured on a receieve!

Comment: This does not really seem like a programming problem to me. Consider finding a better forum to post this question on, like superuser.com or similar.

Comment: Is it a Professional way to give answer of any question, Listen Mattias if you do not know the answer, then please do not bother.

Comment: In my opinion, yes. Superuser might have a better client base for this kind of question. But as these _comments_ of mine are just _comments_, you can choose to ignore them. An answer is something completely different as it should provide you with the means to solve your problem.